# What's the function of cash-in-transit in the phrase cash-in-transit heists

Tags: phrases, adjective-phrases

What's the exact function of "cash-in-transit" here?

Grammar books say that

- "a state-of-the-art computer" is the equal to "a computer which is the state of the art" and "state-of-the-art" is an adjective phrase.

So, with the same idea, can I claim that

- "cash-in-transit" is an adjective phrase and "cash-in-transit heists" means "heists that are cash in transit"

Answer (score 1):

It means stealing cash which is in the process of being moved from one place to another, in other words, theft of cash that is "in transit". Examples could be theft of deposits being moved from a store to a bank, or theft from an armored car moving assets from one bank to another.

Comment: So,
a state-of-the-art computer" means "a computer which is the state of the art", although "cash-in-transit heists" doesn't mean "heists that are cash in transit" but mean "cash heists while cash is in transit". Do I understand it precisely?

Comment: Yes. You could also say that the computer represents the state of the art, more so than being state of the art. There may not be a simple verbal formula to translate an adjective phrase. You have to think of what it could reasonably mean.

Comment: Well, as the last question related to it, If I turn "library books" to "library-in-Oxford books", can you understand as a native speaker that I mean "library books and the library is in Oxford" ?

Comment: No, that would be expressed as "books in a library in Oxford".